# Installing typescript definition manager

Tags: angularjs, typescript

Hi I am trying to install the typescript definition manager (TSD) on my Ubuntu 14.04 VM. I am following the '5 minute tutotial' from Angular.

It says to run

```
npm install -g tsd@^0.6.0
```

After that I am supposed to run

```
tsd install angular2 es6-promise rx rx-lite
```

Anyway, after running the last command Ubuntu simply returns

```
tsd: command not found
```

Can anyone help here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you run the `npm install -g tsd` again, it should output the location where it installs it for you.

In this case that location isn't added to your path variable and you should use a absolute location (or add it to your path).

You should be able to do this in ubuntu by creating a ~/.profile file with

`export PATH=$PATH:/path/to/tsd/folder/`

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer. It is definitely a problem with the path. I followed up the thought of properly updating my nodejs on my Ubuntu VM and ran the cammand again and now it works

Answer (score 0):

The problem in my case seemed to be the nodejs version on my Ubuntu VM. I created a new VM and installed nodejs the following way

```
cd /usr/local/src
wget http://nodejs.org/dist/v0.12.7/node-v0.12.7.tar.gz  
tar -xvzf node-v0.12.7.tar.gz
cd node-v0.12.7
./configure
make
sudo make install
which node
```

After this I could run

```
tsd install angular2 es6-promise rx rx-lite
```

and everything worked as expected. SO I believe updating the my nodejs was the solution. It seems that my old nodejs did not add tsd to the path

Answer (score -1):

> Can anyone help here?

Check your node version. Recommend you use latest `iojs`. It works as shown :

[image]

Comment: apperently I have node version v0.10.36... Is that good or bad?

Comment: note: iojs comes with `node` executable ... doesn't break anything ... just has more stuff, so its a drop in replacement .... that said I just posted what I was using and what does work. YMMV ;)